# What's the term for those sports/games that don't really have offense or defense and are more like exams?

Tags: word-choice, word-request, difference

**NOTE: Please don't nitpick sport vs game in the sense of mind sports or esports as sports.** The point of this post is to ask about opponent vs non-opponent. The reason I said '**sports/games**' is to account for exactly these kinds of nitpicks eg when people say the ff are not sports: chess, 9LX, choker, poker, csgo, valorant, darts, etc. If you don't like the non-physical sports/games, then just pretend I'm talking about, say, basketball vs bowling.

But I do like Mari-Lou A's answer in comment

> Football, basketball, tennis are sports and games. But gymnastics, running, high jump, ice-skating etc. are only sports.

**This is kind of nitpick is fine.**

---

1. Case 1. **For sports/games like bowling, golf and racing games like sprinting and swimming: It's about who gets the most or least** of a certain criteria eg most pins, least/fewest strokes, 1st to reach the goal, etc. In some ways, you don't really have to do the game with your opponent in the same place and at the same time. **What you do and what your opponents do are almost independent.** (BUT say in golf, if your opponent gets a lucky shot, then you might have to take more risky shots or something. But yeah pretty much independent.)
2. Case 2. **But in other sports/games, what you do really depends on what your opponent does**: chess / 9LX, boxing, chessboxing, tennis, fencing, csgo, valorant, basketball, soccer/association football, rugby/American football, poker, choker, etc.

**Question:** What's the term to describe the sports/games that are like **exams** as opposed to sports/games that are really '**games**' in the sense of **having opponents** ?

Comment: Football, basketball, tennis are sports and games. But gymnastics, running, high jump, ice-skating etc.  are only sports.

Comment: @Mari-LouA oh wow really that's it? Kinda anti-climactic. Lol. but thanks. post as answer? also golf is indeed a sport and not a game too?

Comment: If no one answers, I'll post an answer. It seems a little too easy though. Maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: @Mari-LouA yeah i'm not so convinced actually. wikipedia says [sports are games](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Game#Types). in a less strict sense, golf for example is indeed a 'game' in like who can indeed score the fewest strokes?

Comment: It's a game because you compete against someone, you see who completes a golf course using the fewest strokes. People don't have to play it with friends or competitors but it's more fun if you do.

Comment: @Mari-LouA well in a way. BUT if your opponent gets a lucky shot, then you might have to take more risky shots or something? but well potato potahto. yeah i think golf is mostly not a 'game'. thanks

Comment: When asking for a word, can you either explain why you think the word exists (for example you could say "in my my language we call the first type ....." And provide an example sentence   "I don't enjoy sports that are .... I only enjoy sports that are games".  Even so, many single word requests are *hugge*,  for a concept that simply doesn't have a word in English.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I don't think that that's the distinction, because OP puts chess and boxing into the same category even though the former is usually considered more of a game while the latter is never (as far as I'm aware) considered a game. (If you could [combine the two](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pJk0p-98Xzc), though . . .)

Comment: @MarcInManhattan It's been done [for real](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7MBcs5Z4KC4)

Comment: @gotube I never cease to be amazed by what I learn on ELL.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Then there's games that are mostly considered sports, like darts and snooker.

Comment: @JamesK I'm a monolinguist. I'm here of 6 month question ban in english se. (it expires later this month.) lol. but yeah 2 kinds of sports. 1 is independent. 1 is dependent.

Comment: @MarcInManhattan there's going to be a chessboxing thing in december like 2 actual (mainly) chess players are gonna compete in chessboxing. grandmaster aman and im lawrence trent. i don't think chessboxing has ever had this high level of chess players before. the highest i've seen i think is just [fide master carl strugnell.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9eZykcCtkcE)

Comment: @gotube  Darts is not a sport. It's a game of skill, but it doesn't require great physical prowess, because sport is also the celebration of the body, strength, stamina combined with skill. I've heard of people who consider snooker as a sport, because you need intense spells of concentration and dexterity, so I might concede something there. But darts? Never? I've seen too many beer bellied players to ever agree it is a sport.

Comment: No one has even uncorked **competition** as a possible description.  I would consider things like chess and poker to be *competitions* before I considered them games or sports.  I guess chess against my brother might be a game but grandmasters facing off is certainly not.

Comment: @EllieK-Don'tsupporther Love this! So like competition sport(/game) vs non-competition sport(/game)? (I thought like exam sport, solo sport, etc. Eh I think just non-competition sport will do.)

Comment: @Mari-LouA please don't nitpick sport vs game. The point of this post is to ask about opponent vs non-opponent.

Comment: That's not what you said at the beginning and the original focus of the question was sports/games verses games/sports that were more like "exams" without opponents,  which was confusing to me, and explains why I didn't post an answer.

Comment: @Mari-LouA ok thanks. edited post just now to talk about mind sports and esports. I find your 1st comment to be a good answer: case 1 is a sport (or mind sport) and game. case 2 is just a sport (or mind sport).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no common term in English to make this distinction between competitive activities where you're going directly up against each other, versus when you're just seeing who completes first or who completes better in distinct but parallel efforts. In fact, it's such an uncommon distinction that despite your best efforts, almost none of the rather smart people here even understand what you want, let alone what the answer is.

So if you need to make this distinction, you'll likely have to do it the academic way, and *define two terms yourself* in a very well-written preamble. Even then, still expect a good portion of people to get it wrong.

For instance, I propose the two terms, "**shared state game**" (hockey, chess, snooker) and "**parallel state game**" (swimming, golf, darts). Whatever terms you go with, nobody will understand what these terms mean when they first see them. You want terms that make sense *after you understand the new concept*. That's to say, after a few paragraphs and some clarifying examples, anybody comfortable reading simple academic papers should have no trouble following.

Comment: They'll understand if from now I always link this stackexchange post. Thanks gotube♦. Are you like a game theorist or an economist or something? This sounds very game theory like.

Comment: @BCLC My background is teaching ESL. Can I ask why you are interested in this distinction in English?

Comment: gotube♦ I'm a monolinguist with a question ban in english SE only recently lifted. Lol. But in that case as a mathematician, I give you my praise.

Comment: @BCLC Interestingly enough, American football is both. The players in the offensive line are completely different to those in the defensive line for the same team, so OffenceA and DefenceB are playing a shared state game **in parallel** with the shared state game between OffenceB and DefenceA. The scores are added together as the game goes, and the winner is whoever got the most combined points from the two parallel games.

Comment: gotube♦ ah thanks for the info! i have no idea about american football actually. so you a football game is composed of 2 parallel state games each of which is a shared state game? but how though - there's only 1 ball in football?

Comment: @BCLC They go in turns. When the direction of possession changes, the game stops, and all the players on the field switch.

Comment: gotube♦ ah thanks so it's like baseball? or what?

Comment: @BCLC Yes, it's a lot like baseball in that way. There are two parallel state games happening in turns (inning halves), and the winner is the team that scored the most points (runs) during their turns on offence.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure that the exact word exists in English.

There are *sports* and *games*. Games generally involve complex arbitrary rules. For example Football, tennis, snooker, chess and patience (solitaire) are all games. Sports generally involve some aspect of physical skill, strength or power.  Football, Tennis, running, rowing, and snooker and golf are sports.  Many activities are both sports and games.

Games or sports can be designed for teams, or pairs: football and rowing are often team sports (though rowing has a solo form too).  Others are normally individual. Running and snooker are individual sports, and Tennis has both a pairs form and an individual form.

When you speak of "Solo sports", you sometime mean the same as individual sports, and you sometimes mean a sport that you can take part in without any one else: running is an example.

Some sports can be practiced alone, but make more sense as a game: snooker and golf, for example.

Some activities are part of physical fitness, or an exercise program. You might call them a workout.

Your desired category would seem to gather golf, running, solitaire, and rowing.  These are sports and games that don't need an opponent.  And English seems to lack a single term for this group of activities.

**Possible answer:** So, "Solo sports" seems to cover quite a lot of the cases (but there are some team sports that this excludes) but is ambiguous.  I've seen tennis described as a solo sport, even though in this case "individual sport" would be a better term.

Comment: Ah thanks James K! Why can't we just answer 'solo sport/game' for golf, bowling, darts, solitaire, gymnastics, ice skating, etc with 'individual sport/game' for tennis, boxing, chess, chessboxing, poker, etc and 'team sport/game' for basketball, csgo, valorant, bridge, football/rugby/soccer, etc? Unfortunately, on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Individual_sport), tennis, boxing, billiards/pool, etc are with golf, bowling, darts, ice skating, etc. OH BTW, there might be some confusion when you say 'rowing' is a 'solo sport'...maybe solo team sport vs solo individual sport? idk

Answer (score 1):

The best phrase that I can think of that creates the split you've described is "an [endeavour](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/endeavor#English) in which there is no competitor actively opposing your progress."

This captures everything you've placed in "case 1" and none of the things you've placed in "case 2."

As far as I can tell, **there is no word that expresses that concept**.

Comment: I wish that any downvoters would leave a comment indicting what they think is wrong with this answer. In the absence of a comment, the poster cannot improve the answer, others cannot use the reasons to write better answers, and readers have no idea why someone objects to the answer. Such a downvote seems pointless.

Comment: @DavidSiegel, I didn't down-vote, but as soon as I started reading the answer I already didn't like it. The OP uses the term sports/games to indicate that there should be no difference between the two as far as this question is concerned. Yet, the first thing in this answer (and others) is a totally irrelevant comment about the difference between sports and games. Starting off with that sets a bad mood for anyone reading the rest of the answer.

Comment: @Arya, sorry if I sounded like I was picking on your answer. My response was meant to be a possible explanation as requested by DavidSiegel, for why someone else had cast a down-vote. ¶ The designation of "sport" is a sensitive topic for some people, but not usually in a serious way. ( e.g. I once saw a t-shirt saying "It's all fun and games until someone loses an eye — then it's a sport!".) The original question appeared to be asking people not to get into a pointless discussion over what is or is not a "real sport".

Comment: @Arya says "*emphasizes a distinction between some sports/games and those that a "really" games: sports/games that are really 'games'*".  I think the intent is to clarify the distinction that *is* wanted here. For some activities everyone does the best they can individually, and the top one wins.  For some activities there is direct competition and everyone tries to do better than everyone else, but not necessarily their best. The question is asking whether there is terminology for this distinction.

Comment: Thanks @RayButterworth and Arya. I edited post. I just said 'sports/games' because of the nitpicking people would do re physical sports vs mind sports. But I don't mind the use of games in the sense of my most recent edit to include Mari-Lou A's answer in comment: 'Football, basketball, tennis are sports and games. But gymnastics, running, high jump, ice-skating etc. are only sports.'

Answer (score 0):

Your question has completely changed since its first iteration, so I am updating my answer accordingly.

You now seem to be trying to distinguish, not between 'sports' and 'games', but between those played against opponents and those which are not. When you say games that are "more like exams" I can only assume you are speaking about things like *solitaire*, *sudoku* or *crosswords*.

- Things like crosswords and soduku are termed as **puzzles**. These tend to have only one possible solution.
- Solo card games, or *solitaire* games, are considered **games** despite there only being one player. But solitaire games often have various solutions and some depend on luck, so there is a sense that you are playing 'against' the odds or how the cards were dealt.
- Tests of general knowledge, sometimes also undertaken for fun, are usually referred to as **quizzes**.

It is also worth considering that many computer 'games' can be played solo, but are still 'games'. *Puzzle games* are a genre of computer games.

Comment: I would not call Chess, and other games in which there is no element of physic ability, 'sports". This would include most card games and most board games.

Comment: @DavidSiegel Firstly, professional chess players would disagree with you. The longest professional game of chess took over 8 hours, so players would have to be in excellent physical and mental condition to endure that. Secondly, if you really don't think it's a sport, please head over to Wikipedia as you will need to edit out 14 references to the word 'sport'.

Comment: As always, there is no single authoritative source for the meanings of English words. But **I** still would not use the word "sport" for Chess, Bridge, Scrabble, Go, or Poker, (or any similar game) all of which are played professionally, to strict rules and high standards. As a player of tournament bridge myself (although not anywhere near a pro level) I know it takes extended concentration and effort to play well. But I would still not call it a sport. One way to put it: if the late Stephan Hawking could play it, it was not a sport. Obviously, not everyone will agree.

Comment: what is going on? I don't think this answers the question at all. when i say 'sports/games' i actually just mean to account for those people who nitpick and say chess, 9LX, choker, poker csgo and valorant are not 'sports'. my question is really about sports/games where you compete against an opponent vs sports/games where you compete just against yourself. it doesn't matter that 9LX doesn't have a physical element. the point is 9LX has an opponent same as basketball. but rowing, sprinting, swimming don't have opponents same as, say, IQ tests.

Comment: @DavidSiegel what is going on? I don't think this answers the question at all. when i say 'sports/games' i actually just mean to account for those people who nitpick and say chess, 9LX, choker, poker csgo and valorant are not 'sports'. my question is really about sports/games where you compete against an opponent vs sports/games where you compete just against yourself. it doesn't matter that 9LX doesn't have a physical element. the point is 9LX has an opponent same as basketball. but rowing, sprinting, swimming don't have opponents same as, say, IQ tests.

Comment: @BCLC Your question has changed considerably since its first iteration. Perhaps it was not clear originally, as I see most people seem to have perceived that your question was about the difference between 'sports' and 'games', with a focus on which category chess fell into. I've updated my answer to reflect what I now perceive is your question. If this still isn't clear I suggest you consider asking a new question.

Comment: @BCLC  It was not intended to answer your question, merely to comment on an aspect of it, and to respond to the comment of Astralbee. That is why I posted a **comment**, not an **answer**. You already received an answer from Arya that there is no single English word that user knows of with the meaning you seek, and another from Gotub to similar effect. I also do not know of any English word that has such a meaning. Nor do I know of such a word in any other language, but there my knowledge is far less extensive.

Comment: ok thanks for update, re 'more like exams' you said 'I can only assume you are speaking about things' - but i already gave examples? I told you: golf, bowling and racing games/sports

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a division that covers all endeavours (from highly physical sports to mental games to tests of skill). But there are some divisions.

One is [Eurogame](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eurogame) vs American-style games. This applies principally to board games and card games, where a Eurogame (also called European-style or German-style) game involves players working separately to accrue points or resources, such as Carcassonne or Ticket To Ride, and at the end seeing who has the most points. The alternative, called American-style, includes games such as chess or monopoly where competition is about taking your opponent's counters/cards or forcing people out of the game.

Another is [contact sport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contact_sport) vs non-contact sport. In the latter, players are typically segregated or not allowed to come into contact with each other; the former includes sports where some degree of contact is allowed, and includes combat sports (boxing, judo, karate, etc) but also sports such as rugby, American football, water polo, and shinty. There is some debate over a middle category which is sometimes called limited-contact, e.g. basketball or football, where contact is discouraged by penalties but is still common.